# How to create Makefile with includes and libraries?

Tags: c++, mysql, c, makefile

I am trying to create Makefile for my C++ project.

My `main.cpp` contains this custom includes:

```
#include <mysql_connection.h>
#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/exception.h>
#include <cppconn/resultset.h>
#include <cppconn/statement.h>
#include <cppconn/prepared_statement.h>
```

For compilation I use:

```
g++ -stdlib=libc++ -o app.cgi -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/mysql-connector-c++-8.0.21/include/jdbc -L/usr/local/mysql-connector-c++/lib64 main.cpp -lmysqlcppconn
```

Now I need to add

```
#include "tinyxml2/tinyxml2.hpp"
```

The most simple way is to create Makefile. I wrote:

```
CC = g++

CFLAGS = -Wall -g -std=c++11

INCLUDES = -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/mysql-connector-c++-8.0.21/include/jdbc

LDLIBS = -L/usr/local/mysql-connector-c++/lib64 -lmysqlcppconn

SRCS = main.cpp ./tinyxml2/tinyxml2.cpp 

OBJS = $(SRCS:.cpp=.o)

MAIN = main.cgi

#
# The following part of the makefile is generic
#

.PHONY: depend clean

all:    $(MAIN)

$(MAIN): $(OBJS) 
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -o $(MAIN) $(OBJS)

.PRECIOUS: %.o

.c.o:
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -cpp $<  -o $@

clean:
        $(RM) *.o *~ $(MAIN)

depend: $(SRCS)
        makedepend $(INCLUDES) $^
```

I got error:

```
main.cpp:21:10: fatal error: 'mysql_connection.h' file not found
#include <mysql_connection.h>
```

How to add includes to every `.o`? `tinyxml2` doesn't use MySQL connector so I shouldn't add `-lmysqlcppconn`. How to do it?

Comment: Why did you add jdbc to mysql connector?

Comment: cppconn files are hidden there.

Comment: I'm not able to find information about the parameter `-cpp` in `$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -cpp $<  -o $@`. What does it mean? _"`$<` is a macro that refers to the first dependency"_ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makefile But `.c.o:` doesn't have any dependencies.

Comment: Why do you use `-stdlib=libc++` in `g++ -stdlib=libc++ -o app.cgi -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/mysql-connector-c++-8.0.21/include/jdbc -L/usr/local/mysql-connector-c++/lib64 main.cpp -lmysqlcppconn`?

Comment: Nothing in your makefile tells it to use `$(INCLUDES)` when it compiles cpp files. So, it doesn't.

Comment: If you post the compile line that make invokes which it will print just before the error messages, you will clearly see what's wrong (your compile flags are missing).

Comment: Beyond the other comments, using `.PRECIOUS: %.o` is a bad idea.  Also (as mentioned below) you set the `LDLIBS` variable but then never use it anywhere.  It's sure been a long time since I've seen `makedepend`!  This makefile feels like it's straight out of the 1990s or so :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build the makefile step by step. Start with the build command and make it a makefile target (I removed `-stdlib=libc++`):

```
app.cgi: main.cpp
    g++ -o app.cgi -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/mysql-connector-c++-8.0.21/include/jdbc -L/usr/local/mysql-connector-c++/lib64 main.cpp -lmysqlcppconn
```

Next you can extract most elements into variables and add compiler flags:

```
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -Wall -g -std=c++11
MAIN = app.cgi
CPPFLAGS = -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/mysql-connector-c++-8.0.21/include/jdbc
SRCS = main.cpp
LDFLAGS = -L/usr/local/mysql-connector-c++/lib64
LDLIBS = -lmysqlcppconn

$(MAIN): $(SRCS)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -o $(MAIN) $(SRCS) $(LDFLAGS) $(LDLIBS)
```

Add a `clean` and an `all` target:

```
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -Wall -g -std=c++11
MAIN = app.cgi
CPPFLAGS = -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/mysql-connector-c++-8.0.21/include/jdbc
SRCS = main.cpp
LDFLAGS = -L/usr/local/mysql-connector-c++/lib64
LDLIBS = -lmysqlcppconn

.PHONY: all clean

all:    $(MAIN)

$(MAIN): $(SRCS)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -o $(MAIN) $(SRCS) $(LDFLAGS) $(LDLIBS)

clean:
    $(RM) *.o *~ $(MAIN)
```

Split into compiler step (implicit makefile rule) and linker step:

```
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -Wall -g -std=c++11
MAIN = app.cgi
CPPFLAGS = -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/mysql-connector-c++-8.0.21/include/jdbc
SRCS = main.cpp
OBJS = $(SRCS:.cpp=.o)
LDFLAGS = -L/usr/local/mysql-connector-c++/lib64
LDLIBS = -lmysqlcppconn

.PHONY: all clean

all:    $(MAIN)

$(MAIN): $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) -o $(MAIN) $(OBJS) $(LDFLAGS) $(LDLIBS)

clean:
    $(RM) *.o *~ $(MAIN)
```

Finally add `./tinyxml2/tinyxml2.cpp`:

```
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -Wall -g -std=c++11
MAIN = app.cgi
CPPFLAGS = -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/mysql-connector-c++-8.0.21/include/jdbc
SRCS = main.cpp ./tinyxml2/tinyxml2.cpp
OBJS = $(SRCS:.cpp=.o)
LDFLAGS = -L/usr/local/mysql-connector-c++/lib64
LDLIBS = -lmysqlcppconn

.PHONY: all clean

all:    $(MAIN)

$(MAIN): $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) -o $(MAIN) $(OBJS) $(LDFLAGS) $(LDLIBS)

clean:
    $(RM) *.o *~ $(MAIN)
```

Comment: Really, it's better to use the `CXX` and `CXXFLAGS` variables, if you're building C++ code.  Also, it's better to use the `CPPFLAGS` variable to hold preprocessor flags, rather than `INCLUDES`.  If you do this then you don't need to define your own pattern rule for `%.o : %.cpp` at all: make's built-in rule will do it for you.  I realize you're trying to work with the settings from the original but if we're completely rewriting the makefile anyway might as well make it use more best practices :)